# Accessing the Aleph API with PHP, always getting error "No schema is specified for the query."

Tags: php, api, elasticsearch, aleph

I'm trying to access the OCCRP Aleph API

https://redocly.github.io/redoc/?url=https://aleph.occrp.org/api/openapi.json

with the following PHP program

```
$url = 'https://aleph.occrp.org/api/2/entities?q="title:bank"';
$ch = curl_init();
$headeroptions = array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: ApiKey 363af1e2b03b41c6b3adc604956e2f66');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headeroptions);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
$array = json_decode($data, true);  
Var_dump($array);
```

I always get the error "No schema is specified for the query."

When I call Statistics, I get a correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

after inspecting how the API works in their own website, I've notice you're missing a required parameter, which indicates the schema. Just add this to your url:

```
&filter:schemata=Thing
```

and it should work